# Pulling Multiple Ranges from Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Lets say I have the following data set:

```
A      B    
10.1   53
12.5   42
16.0   37
20.7   03
25.6   16
30.1   01
40.9   19
60.5   99
```

I have a the following list of ranges.

```
[[9,15],[19,22],[39,50]]
```

How do I efficiently pull rows that lie in those ranges?

Wanted Output

```
A      B    
10.1   53
12.5   42
20.7   03
40.9   19
```

Edit:
Needs to work for floating points

Comment: Tbh, I don't get why `53` and `3` are within those ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update for modified question**

For floats, you can construct a mask using NumPy array operations:

```
L = np.array([[9,15],[19,22],[39,50]])
A = df['A'].values

mask = ((A >= L[:, 0][:, None]) & (A <= L[:, 1][:, None])).any(0)

res = df[mask]

print(res)

      A   B
0  10.1  53
1  12.5  42
3  20.7   3
6  40.9  19
```

---

**Previous answer to original question**

For integers, you can use `numpy.concatenate` with `numpy.arange`:

```
L = [[9,15],[19,22],[39,50]]

vals = np.concatenate([np.arange(i, j) for i, j in L])

res = df[df['A'].isin(vals)]

print(res)

    A   B
0  10  53
1  12  42
3  20   3
6  40  19
```

An alternative solution with `itertools.chain` and `range`:

```
from itertools import chain

vals = set(chain.from_iterable(range(i, j) for i, j in L))

res = df[df['A'].isin(vals)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method (edit: works with floats or integers). @jpp's might be faster, but this code is easier to understand (in my opinion).

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[10.1,53],[12.5,42],[16.0,37],[20.7,3],[25.6,16],[30.1,1],[40.9,19],[60.5,99]],columns=list('AB'))
ranges = [[9,15],[19,22],[39,50]]  

result = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('AB'))
for r in ranges:
    result = result.append(df[df['A'].between(r[0], r[1], inclusive=False)])

print (result)
```

Here's the output:

```
      A   B
0  10.1  53
1  12.5  42
3  20.7   3
6  40.9  19
```

PS: the following one-line list comprehension also works:

`result = result.append([source[source['A'].between(r[0], r[1], inclusive=False)] for r in ranges])`